# PHP Variable in HTML

Tags: javascript, php, html

I need help with a php variable that will refresh every 2 seconds and I need it to go to my .html page.

The php code:

```
<?php
            $raw = file_get_contents('https://www.instagram.com/USERNAME');
            preg_match('/\"followed_by\"\:\{\"count\"\:([0-9]+)/', $raw, $m);
?>
```

This retrieves an INT from the instagram website of a username. 
I can print the INT like this:

```
<?php 
print intval($m[1]) 
?>
```

Now I need this variable into my .html page to get them into a javascript counter.

**How do I 'move' this INT variable every 5 seconds to my .html page?**

Comment: Your page is constructed *once*, and delivered to the user's browser *once*. If you want to refresh a portion of that document every *n* seconds, you'll want to use JavaScript.

Comment: Oh come on, there's a kajillion questions like this one on SO.

Comment: So... do you really believe there will be a difference in number of followers every five seconds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use JS/jQuery to query server every 5 seconds to get new value:

```
<span id="int"><?php echo $m[1]; ?></span>

setInterval(function () {
    $('#int').load('getInt.php');
},
5000);

[getInt.php]

$raw = file_get_contents('https://www.instagram.com/USERNAME');
preg_match('/\"followed_by\"\:\{\"count\"\:([0-9]+)/', $raw, $m);

echo $m[1];
```